# Bootstrap 5 Button collapse and carousel

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I want to implement two buttons with Bootstrap 5. One button activates two JavaScript functions that open a bootstrap carousel. The other button is a simple collapse button that should open a long text string.

The collapse button does not work. I assume that it has something to do with the way I have implemented Bootrap 5. However, I cannot figure out a solution.

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display === 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }


     function blur_function(id) {
        var g = document.getElementById(id);
        if(g.style.filter === "blur(5px)")
          g.style.filter = "none";
       else
          g.style.filter = "blur(5px)";
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button id="button_search_decision" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="blur_function('tax'); toggle_visibility('carouselExampleControls')">Belege einsehen</button>

    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="Bild 1">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="Bild2">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="Bild 3">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="Bild 4">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
       </div>


    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-bs-target
    </button>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="card card-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The collapse button is working perfectly well in what you posted. Could you create a [mcve] where it's actually not working (a.k.a. *"reproduce the bug"*)? In other words, something in your environment, which you haven't included here, is causing the bug. Until you add it here and make the bug reproducible, your question is technically unanswerable.

Comment: Where is the element with id `tax`?

Comment: You are right. I have tried both buttons in a blank html file and they are working perfectly well. I have been working in the python based framework oTree. I strongly assume that the framework causes the bug. Many thanks!

Comment: @tao I have been working in otree for a while and it is very problematic to make the minimal reproducible example. otree has many dependencies and things wrapped up in other things which conflict without apparent reason. I have been stuck at the same problem for days, and yes. When I paste everything into jsfiddle everything works.

Answer (score 0):

As of mid-2022, despite the claims from otree's documentation, it does not work properly with Bootstrap.

There are way too many missing indications in the documentation which makes bootstrap virtually unusable.

My advice is to focus on manually coding the bootstrap elements whenever possible. Accordions are easy, you can check one example [here that does not use javascript](https://supfort.com/pure-css-accordion-without-javascript).

Unfortunately I cannot comment on the carousel.

This is probably not the answer you were looking for, but unfortunately otree5 is nowhere near to have a working bootstrap implementation.